# problem with xpath i'm getting invalid url trying to scrap

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath

I have the following problem with my code. I'm trying to scrap information of the next link
[sepomex](https://www.correosdemexico.gob.mx/SSLServicios/ConsultaCP/Descarga.aspx)

I'm trying to get the Estado, Municipio and a list of cp (código postal btw) but I'm getting this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuQ22.jpg)

and this is my code:

```
import os
import datetime
import requests
import lxml.html as html

HOME_URL = 'https://www.correosdemexico.gob.mx/SSLServicios/ConsultaCP/Descarga.aspx'

XPATH_ESTADOS = '//select[@id="DdlEstado"]/option[@value > 0]/text()'
XPATH_MUNICIPIOS = '//select[@id="DdlMunicipio"]/option[@value > 0]/text()'
XPATH_LOCALIDAD = '//table[@class="small"]/tbody/tr[@class="dgNormal"]/td/text()'


def parse_edos(estado, today):
    try:
        response = requests.get(estado)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            root = html.fromstring(response.content)

            try:
                municipios = root.xpath(XPATH_MUNICIPIOS)
                for municipio in municipios:
                    localidad = root.xpath(XPATH_LOCALIDAD)
            except IndexError:
                return
            with open(f'{today}/{estado}.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
                for i in localidad:
                    f.write(i + '\n')
        else:
            raise ValueError(f'Error: {response.status_code}')

    except ValueError as err:
        print(err)


def main():
    try:
        response = requests.get(HOME_URL)
        if response.status_code == 200:
            root = html.fromstring(response.content)
            estados = root.xpath(XPATH_ESTADOS)
            today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
            if not os.path.isdir(today):
                os.mkdir(today)

            for estado in estados:
                parse_edos(estado, today)

        else:
            raise ValueError(f'Error: {response.status_code}')
    except ValueError as err:
        print(err)


def run():
    main()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

srry about my kewl english :P

Comment: Please, do not post text (code, logs, etc.) as images. second, you already have the page response, this is wrong: `response = requests.get(estado)`

Comment: The page has a limit of 2000 records, so its needed to search by state and check if this happens. I recommend using selenium to dynamically get the state list and fire the query one by one, testing if the error appears (when it will be needed to parse by municipio (county). Other way could be asking to INEGI (the national statistics institute) for the raw data, URL: https://www.inegi.org.mx/.